# bash argval not read

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Here is the content of my bash script:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 set INPFILE=$argv[1]

 echo "Your input file is "
 echo $INPFILE
```

and I execute it as:

```
 $ ./script.sh inputfile.in
```

For some reason, bash doesn't accept the `argval[1]`. I do not receive an error either.

BTW, the output is:

```
 Your input file is
```

Comment: You will have to learn to be precise.  You script references `$argv[1]`; your question asks about `argval[1]` — the names are wholly unrelated.  You need to read the manual on [positional parameters](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Positional-Parameters) and eventually on [arrays](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays).  Immediately, you need to use `$1`, which is the positional parameter notation.

Comment: Incidentally, Bash is not a C shell derivative so you don't need to use the [`set`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin) command like that, either.  It doesn't do what you seem to think it does.  You could usefully add `echo "$1"` at the end of your script to see what you are doing.

Comment: `echo $INPFILE` is also wrong (doesn't work in all cases) -- look at what happens when `$1` is `-n`, or `"*"`. Use `printf '%s\n' "$INPFILE"` instead. Also, using at least one lower-case character in variable names avoids overwriting system variables, and is in line with best practices; see also the fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html on environment variable naming convention, keeping in mind that shell variables and environment variables share a namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `set INPFILE=$argv[1]` to:

```
INPFILE="$1"
```

$1, $2, $3 .... etc are the positional parameters passed to the script/function.

[See the manual for more info.](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameters)